# Eager load associations on STI subclasses when joining to parent class with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sti

`Product` has a oneToMany relationship with `Deliverable`. Using STI I have defined several types of deliverable such as `DigitalDeliverable` and `MerchDeliverable` which subclass `Deliverable`.

`DigitalDeliverable` has a oneToMany self-referencing association; a `DigitalDeliverable` may have a `parent` or many `children`.

I need to write a DQL query that loads some products and eagerly loads all referenced deliverables. This is what I am attempting to do:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p', 'd', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('p.deliverables', 'd')
    ->leftJoin('d.children', 'c');
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Which causes this error:
`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 136 near 'c LEFT JOIN d.pricings': Error: Class Deliverable has no association named children`

If I move the self-referencing association from `DigitalDeliverable` to its, parent `Deliverable`, then the query executes but that defeats the point of using table inheritance. For example, a `MerchDeliverable` shouldn't have the self-referencing attributes.

**How can I eagerly load the self-referencing association on DigitalDeliverable?**

The following gist contains the entity definitions and query: https://gist.github.com/peterhorne/5831829

*(I've omitted attributes on entities and clauses in the query that aren't relevant to the question)*